# WP8: can my App read file that is stored in internal memory by user?

Tags: memory, storage, windows-phone-8

If I copy my files (text based *.lrc) to WP8 device's (Lumia 920) internal memory through USB connection, can my App read them? Or it is only allowed to read from isolated storage? what path would be if I just copy to root of the internal memory? There are APIs to read registered files from SD card. Is there a way to do that for internal memory (mass storage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to launch specified file types using File Associations in WP8. Check this article for more details:
[Auto-launching apps using file and URI associations for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

> File associations allow your app to automatically launch when the user
>   wants to open a particular file. That file could come from a variety
>   of sources including, but not limited to:
>
> - an email attachment
> - a website via Internet Explorer
> - a Near Field Communications (NFC) tag
> - another app from the Store

Comment: Thanks. My intent is not to be launched, instead my App is trying to read files stored by user. For those device without SD card, there is no way for app to access files stored in internal memory. Expecting end user to copy stuff to isolatedstorage is not much possible.